# Foundation for Sites : What is the purpose of adding the class "columns" ?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I use these code-snippet :

```
 class="large-6 small-12 columns ..."
```

When I remove the "columns"-class so that it is

```
class="large-6 small-12"
```

... I see no difference.

So I'm wondering:

What is the "columns"-class for?

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: In case you want to add generic styling to all the columns, like the same padding or background colour or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`columns` or `column` have some basic CSS attached to them;

```
.column, .columns {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: .625rem; /* you can set this in the CSS generator or SASS */
    padding-right: .625rem; /* you can set this in the CSS generator or SASS */
}
```

Without the `.column` class the columns won't line up in their rows.

[JSFiddle example with and without](https://jsfiddle.net/kwtwcwb6/1/)

Comment: I think I understand now. It's for to prevent the div-elements breaking into a new line? Instead the shall order one after the other within one line ...

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The `float: left;` makes it a row, the padding is the "gutter" and the `width: 100%` is for (I think) when the row and column is combined. Width is overwritten by the `medium-6` or whatever if you use it.

Comment: Awesome. :) Thanks a lot.